# Why salesforce lightning experience is ironically sluggish?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, aura, performance

Why lightning experience is ironically sluggish?

The classic experience comparatively feels faster when it comes to page load time and navigation.

Have seen may developers and admins prefer classic experience unless we are developing or testing lighting experience specific functionality.

In few encounters in past have seen that, while developing public sites where performance is the prime concern people pefer other web technonloigics.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're using [Enable Secure Browser Caching](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/perf_secure_browser_caching.htm), and that you did not [Enable Debug Mode for Lightning Components](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.aura_debug_mode.htm&type=5). Keep in mind that the user experience will very greatly depending on how many components have to load, what server calls they need to make, efficient use of Arrays and other collections that are Proxy'd by [Lightning Locker Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_code.htm).

Aside from the initial load, there's no reason why Lightning needs to be sluggish. The default UI is (usually) perfectly fine, it tends to be poorly made components that cause delays. It may also be that it "feels" sluggish because it has loading screens, while Classic is just a plain white screen until everything loads.

I've found loading times are usually comparable, or faster, to other [Web Component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) frameworks, such as React. I will admit there's a pretty hefty performance hit for Locker Service, which other frameworks usually don't offer, to make sure that all data is secure. This extra security means that developers have to be careful about how they write their code to minimize bottlenecks.

It's true that other frameworks may seem faster, but that's really a tuning problem. In order to have a fair comparison, you'd have to have an apples-to-apples comparison set up.

Comment: Worth mentioning that Aura is much slower to process than LWC and that if loading and processing time is poor check whether Aura is in use and, if possible, replace with LWC.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever used the [Lighthouse Tool](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/?utm_source=devtools)? You can access it from your browser developer console. It will give you some insight to what is happening. Lightning prioritizes the ability to load the page quickly before all content is available. Notice how Lightning shows [Loading Stencils (also known as Skeletons)](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/guidelines/loading/) to indicate that it is actively retrieving data. Whereas classic prioritizes having all the data ready before the page is displayed.

What this does is give Lightning a better [First Contentful Paint](https://web.dev/first-contentful-paint/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=devtools) but a worse [Time to Interactive](https://web.dev/interactive/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=devtools) score. I'd say this is probably due to all the asynchronous requests that Lightning performs to retrieve the data for each component.

Give the Lighthouse tool a try for a page you notice an issue in your org. Try it in Lightning and Classic. Try it with a Lightning page with a few out of the box SF components and mimic that in Classic and see what you find out. I've found that lightning adds some overhead but the flexibility of the modern component based framework outweighs the added overhead/time, in my opinion.